# Coloring problem by Paul Erdos

Tags: probability, coloring

We consider the following coloring problem, which goes back to the famous Hungarian mathematician Paul Erdős. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of $d$-sets, $d \geq 2$, from an underlying set $X$. We say that $\mathcal{F}$ is 2-colorable if there exists a coloring of the elements of $X$ with two colors such that in every set $A \in \mathcal{F}$, both colors occur.

It is clear that not every family $\mathcal{F}$ can be thus colored. If, for example, $\mathcal{F}$ is the family of all $d$-subsets of a $(2 d-1)$-set, then by the pigeonhole principle, there must be a $d$-set of a single color. On the other hand, it is also clear that every subfamily of a two-colorable family is itself two-colorable. We would like to know the smallest number $m=m(d)$ for which there exists a family $\mathcal{F}$ with $|\mathcal{F}|=m$ that is not two-colorable. We want to prove that $m(d)>2^{d-1}$.

**Here is a solution from Martin Aigner in Discrete mathematics book.**

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be given, with $|\mathcal{F}| \leq 2^{d-1}$. We color $X$ randomly with two colors, whereby all colorings are equally probable. For $A \in \mathcal{F}$ let $E_A$ be the event that the elements of $A$ all have the same color. Since there are exactly two such colorings on $A$, we obtain
$$
p\left(E_A\right)=\frac{2}{2^d}=\frac{1}{2^{d-1}} .
$$
Thus with $|\mathcal{F}| \leq 2^{d-1}$ (where the events are not disjoint),
$$
p\left(\bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{F}} E_A\right)<\sum_{A \in \mathcal{F}} p\left(E_A\right)=m \frac{1}{2^{d-1}} \leq 1 .
$$
Now $\bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{F}} E_A$ is the event that some set in $\mathcal{F}$ is of a single color, and we conclude from $p\left(\bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{F}} E_A\right)<1$ that there must exist a two-coloring of $S$ without single-colored sets, which is just what we wanted to show.
**My question:**

1. How can they make sure that $\forall A, B \in \mathcal{F}$ then $E_A \cap E_B \ne \emptyset$
2. What is the probabilistic model for that experience? (Universal $\Omega$ and probability $\mathbb{P}$)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For all $A, B$, we can color $A$ with two distinct colors (since $|A| \geq 2$). If $A\cap B = \emptyset$, we do the same for $B$, if $A = B$, $B$ is colored with two distinct colors. Else, we color an element of $B - A$ with the other color than a arbitrary element of $A\cap B$. We color the remaining elements arbitrarily. This coloring is in $E_A \cap E_B$, so it is not empty.
2. $\Omega$ is the set of all the coloring of the graph (not proper, so there might be a set that has all the vertices the same color).

   $\mathbb{P}$ is the uniform distribution over $\Omega$. This is obtained simply by choosing for each vertex a color with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ for each of the two colors.